# Unexpected char printed in console

Tags: c++, c++11

```
int main()
{
  char j[] = "abc";
  print(j);
}
```

When I define `print` like this:

```
void print(const char *cp)
{
  if (cp)
  {
    while (*cp)
    {
      int i = *cp;
      cout << *cp;
      // cout << *cp << endl;
      cp++;
    }
  }
}
```

The console is something like this (I can not copy the result property, so I use a screenshot)
[image]
The `%` like character is quite expected

However, when I put the `endl` the wired `%` character disappear

```
void print(const char *cp)
{
  if (cp)
  {
    while (*cp)
    {
      int i = *cp;
      // cout << *cp;
      cout << *cp << endl;
      cp++;
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Could anyone help explain what happen?

I do not think `%` is not part of the prompt
[image]

I change my prompt the a text 'a', and the `%` still present
[image]

Comment: It's because `%` is from the prompt you get from the operating system after the program has finished. It's not coming from the program itself. Adding a ```\n``` (or `std::endl`) after you've printed all characters makes it "look normal". Show what `run.sh` looks like or run the program from the prompt instead.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I updated the question, and I put the full screenshot, the `%` seem not to be a part of prompt

Comment: I also updated my comment. Please show `run.sh` or just run the program from the prompt instead of via `run.sh`. Alt. try [this](https://godbolt.org/z/PPfa3PEP6)

Comment: @TedLyngmo When I run it by clicking the executable from my mac, I can not see the `%`, however when I run it in terminal by `./prog` the `%` still present. It is still very unobvious to me how the possible part of prompt, Thet seems very irrelevant

Comment: From the screenshot you can see my prompt is not start with `%` at all

Comment: It's not irrelevant. Change your prompt to something very different, like a static text, `PROMPT` without escape sequences in it. It's not starting with `%` but it's ending with it, possibly with escape sequences in it.

Comment: Did you try the code I gave you? No problem, right?

Comment: I change my prompt the a text 'a', and the `%` still present
See the screenshot @TedLyngmo

Comment: I suppose you are right, It may be part of the prompt. But I because I do not have a good understanding of the system, I can not confirm it. I think your opinion make some sense though

Comment: It's not coming from the program. At least that much I can tell you. :-) Are you running this from a pure shell or from a shell started from within an IDE? What shell is it? Perhaps the shell uses that inverted `%` to signal that there was no newline at the end. Try this command: `echo -n Hello` and see if you get a `%` after that too

Comment: run from the integrated terminal of vscode, the `%` disappear after I add an `endl` as you say. So I believe it not part of the program

Comment: Aha, don't. Run it from a pure shell. The IDE shells often mess things like this up.

Comment: Why is this ever a question? Always, always, always print a newline at the end of your output. There are no ifs or buts or maybes or howevers. Just do it.

Comment: Some shells – like `zsh`– print a `%` (inverted) and a newline if a program's output didn't end with a newline, and some shells don't. It's not part of either the prompt or your output, but it's a feature that avoids the actual prompt ending up in strange places.

Comment: @n.m. could you point me some source?

Comment: @molbdnilo your explanation sound like make the most sense

Comment: Yes, @molbdnilo confirmed my suspicion that the shell may print that to signal that the program output did not end with a newline. Did you try `echo -n Hello`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo `echo -n Hello` has the same `%` effect, you can put a detailed explanation as a answer

Comment: Do you want confusion? Don't print the newline then. Hate confusion? Print the newline. Do you need a source for that? *This question of yours is the source*.

Comment: Change title from "*Unexpected char printed in console*" to "*Expected char printed by the shell in console*".

Comment: @Eljay you can add a answer of detailed explanation about where the `%` come from, I also wonder there is not a similar question in stackoverflow and there is limited source on the internet about such shell behaviour

Comment: @Guichi See [`zsh`Options#Prompting](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html#Prompting): From `PROMPT_SP`: _"When a partial line is preserved, by default you will see an inverse+bold character at the end of the partial line: a ‘%’ for a normal user or a ‘#’ for root."_

Comment: And here's a [detailed description](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/302710/391809) of how it does it.

Comment: There's not much to it.  Your shell detects that the cursor was not left on a newline.  Your shell prints an inverted `%` and *newline*, rather than abutting the prompt with the mid-line output from the process that just finished.

Comment: @Eljay It's a little more low-tech than that if the explanation in the link I shared is correct :-)